# Azure Api Managment: Function app seems not to be invoked?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/import-function-app-as-api) provided by Microsoft Azure to import a Function App within Api Management. I achieved to import my function and to test it by sending a Http Request (method GET), I got a Http Response with a code 200 OK. However, there is no content (content-length: 0) but it has to return a json string in the body. It seems that the function app is not invoked. This is something I checked when I test individually my function app.

Do you have an idea why there is no content ?

Thanks

Comment: Fount it: https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2017/10/24/azure-api-management-200-ok-response-but-no-backend-traffic/ !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST API service when called from azure APIM returning empty response body with Status code 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428300/rest-api-service-when-called-from-azure-apim-returning-empty-response-body-with)