# Azure API Management returning 200 status without response body

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, ibm-api-management

I already have checked other solutions available on the forum and this one too
[REST API service when called from azure APIM returning empty response body with Status code 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40428300/rest-api-service-when-called-from-azure-apim-returning-empty-response-body-with)

I'm trying to call an authentication service which returns status codes (200,401 and 404)
If it returns 200 then I want my request to be forwarded to the backend otherwise return only status code back to the client.

This is what I added in my policy

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <check-header name="username" failed-check-httpcode="401" failed-check-error-message="unauthorised" ignore-case="true" />
    <cors>
        <allowed-origins>
            <origin>*</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods>
            <method>GET</method>
            <method>POST</method>
        </allowed-methods>
    </cors>
    <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="receivedResp" timeout="20" ignore-error="true">
        <set-url>https://authenticate1.azurewebsites.net/auth</set-url>
        <set-method>GET</set-method>
        <set-header name="username" exists-action="override">
            <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("username",""))</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body />
    </send-request>
    <return-response response-variable-name="receivedResp" />
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

Now problem is return is returning received response in all cases, when i added a conditional policy i still was not able to return response received from backend.

**Can anyone tell how to check status code and return response received from the server in case of 200 only?**

Comment: Have you enabled application insights for APIM

Comment: @Inzi no but I have tested API by API inspector. I'm not able to get response from backend because redirection occurs before that and if I remove redirection then gathered response is not sent back to API client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<send-request/>` policy returns the response variable of type `context.Response`. So you can use the methods and variables available for that object. See the below reference to find it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ref-context-response

In your case, you can add `<choose/>` policy and test the 
`receivedResp.StatusCode != 200`. Then you can return based on the response.

Hope it helps

Comment: In addition return-response without response-variable-name should be used to return only status code and not the whole response from auth service.